# How can I get the latest JRE / JDK as a zip file rather than EXE or MSI installer?

Tags: java, installation

I like to be sure that everything will work just by copying the contents of the Java folder and setting the environment variables.

I usually run the installer in a virtual machine, zip the \java folder contents, go back to a snapshot of the virtual machine, and then unzip the compressed file.

I couldn't find a place where the latest JRE / JDK is available as a zip file...

http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp

http://download.java.net/jdk6/

Alternately, is it safe to assume that exe installer from sun just will just unzip the whole thing, without messing around with the registry, environment variables, etc...?

#### Related: [Installing Java manually on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930265/installing-java-manually-on-windows)

--
After all this time I found [this](https://installbuilder.bitrock.com/java/) site that seems to be exactly what I was looking for (2018-05-22)

Comment: Java installer will (or at least should) set JAVA_HOME. Probably it does other things too as the Java will probably not find its way to the Windows Control Panel by itself. And as far as I know, there's no ZIP available from Sun. Though I've never tried to find one.

Comment: "... but I like to be sure that just by copying the contents of the java folder and setting the environment variables, everything will work fine.".  WHY?

Comment: public jre's mess with the windows folders to provide a java.exe in the default path.

Comment: yeap, that's the sort of things I'm trying to avoid...

Comment: In support of this question: I have to install a JRE by hand to avoid my company's tendency to break it with "Fixes" remotely installed.  Currently I install it, copy it then uninstall it to hide it from them--seems kind of annoying but the way it is now breaks our entire dev setup with every patch.

Comment: With the release of Java 8 Oracle provides an archive that doesn't need installation - although only for the JRE: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html and http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html (download the .tar.gz files)

Comment: @Carlos I cannot tell you how many times I've had to manually set JAVA_HOME on all the different computers I install Java on. When I format my computer, it always burns me because Maven requires it to be set and forces me to fix it. I do not know why it fails to set for me yet works for others (since I've had this problem on Windows XP, 7, and 8). I always thought that the installer was supposed to do that for me but just ended up doing it myself out of frustration.

Comment: Can I just copy the jdk installation  folder from another computer to mine without install it ?

Comment: Since quite some time Oracle offers  tar.gz for Windows 32 and 64 bit on the official download page, and there is also the Windows x64 server-jre bundles.

Comment: From JDK 11 we can get the zip download for windows directly from oracle website.

Comment: https://installbuilder.com/java/  -> answer

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can download a Java Portable from [PortableApps.com](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable). It will not change your system settings. You can put it on your USB stick.

UPD: for those who needs JDK there's an open-source project [OpenJDK Portable](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openjdkportable/)

UPD2: there is also a [JDK Portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/jdkportable64) (Oracle)

Some people might be interested in official Oracle [production-ready open source build of JDK](https://jdk.java.net/)

Comment: That's great, but it's only a JRE, not a JDK.

Comment: @Vivien, if OpenJDK works for you there is OpenJDK Portable project - http://sourceforge.net/projects/openjdkportable/

Comment: For **Windows** OpenJDK Portable see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991508/openjdk-availability-for-windows-os

Comment: It would be better if it was provider by Oracle.

Comment: Update: [PortableApps now offers a portable version of the Java JDK.](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/jdkportable)

Comment: PortableApps 64 bit Java JDK (https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/jdkportable64) is no longer downloadable.  Link page comes up but actual download is no longer on the server.

Comment: This one works perfectly: https://portapps.io/app/oracle-jdk-portable/

Answer (score 561):

JDK is not available as a portable ZIP file, unfortunately. However, you can follow these steps:

- Create working JDK directory (`C:\JDK` in this case)
- [Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) latest version of JDK from Oracle (for example `jdk-7u7-windows-x64.exe`)
- [Download](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) and install 7-Zip (or download [7-Zip portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/7-zip_portable) version if you are not administrator)
- With 7-Zip extract all the files from `jdk-XuXX-windows-x64.exe` into the directory `C:\JDK`
- Execute the following commands in `cmd.exe`:

  - `cd C:\JDK\.rsrc\1033\JAVA_CAB10`
  - `extrac32 111`
- Unpack `C:\JDK\.rsrc\1033\JAVA_CAB10\tools.zip` with 7-zip
- Execute the following commands in `cmd.exe`:

  - `cd C:\JDK\.rsrc\1033\JAVA_CAB10\tools\`
  - `for /r %x in (*.pack) do .\bin\unpack200 -r "%x" "%~dx%~px%~nx.jar"` (this will convert all `.pack` files into `.jar` files)
- Copy all contents of `C:\JDK\.rsrc\1033\JAVA_CAB10\tools` where you want your JDK to be
- Setup `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` manually to point to your JDK dir and its BIN subdirectory.

Comment: This doesn't register the DLLs though, so the debugging tools like `jmap` or `jhat` won't work.

Comment: When I did this, I would get an error : Error occurred during initialization of VM java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object.

The problem is that the unpack200 command above renames the .pack files to .pack.jar, and I believe the java executable expects them to be named just .jar. I am not expert enough in Windows scripting to know how to change that command, so I manually went into each folder and where there was a file names x.pack.jar, I renamed it to x.jar, and got rid of the .pack file.

Comment: If you want to automate it, once you have 7-zip installed you can just use the 7z.exe utility that's installed along with it to do all the extraction (it also replaces extrac32 in this solution). So for example: `7z e jdk-7u15-windows-x64.exe .rsrc/JAVA_CAB10/111` `7z e 111` `7z x -ojdk_dir tools.zip` and then delete the temporary 111 and tools.zip files and do the unpacking. The unpacking under msys/cygwin can be done with: `find jdk_dir -name "*.pack" -exec sh -c 'jdk_dir/bin/unpack200 -r "{}" "$(dirname "{}")/$(basename "{}" .pack).jar"' \;`.

Comment: If you want the src.zip, then you should also "extrac32 110" in .rsrc/JAVA_CAB9, and copy that to the root of your resulting JDK directory.

Comment: It appears that as of JDK 7u40, the exe file has tools.zip directly inside it, so you should skip the cab (111) steps and just extract tools.zip directly from the exe and continue from there.

Comment: This works, but as others mentioned, the exe has the tools.zip directly in there now. Maybe this is due to how 7zip extraction has changed. In any case, thanks for the loop to unpack the .pack files into jars.

Comment: I didn't have an .rsrc folder, so what I did is run the unpack200 step on the C:\JDK folder itself and that worked. (JDK 8u65)

Comment: @AlixLourme same is true for jdk-6u45-windows-x64, the file is in `.rsrc\1033\JAVA_CAB10`

Comment: for /r %x in (*.pack) do .\bin\unpack200 -r "%x" "%~dx%~px%~nx.jar" (this will convert all .pack files into .jar files)        this is the only important step here thanks!

Comment: Here is [unpack-jdk-x64.bat](https://gist.github.com/grabantot/402a4acf63f81ba754b26e2dce1b16a3#file-unpack-jdk-x64-bat) to do all of the steps above. Don't forget to set 7z location at the top of the file. JDK will be unpacked to a folder named jdk, all temp files will be removed.

Comment: For jdk-8u131-windows-x64, the  111 file is in (second archive) `jdk-8u131-windows-x64.exe/.rsrc/RCDATA/100/.rsrc/1033/JAVA_CAB10/111`

Comment: @AlixLourme I don't have an RCDATA directory in .rsrc after extracting the same file just now.

Comment: @Trejkaz: I have rechecked on `jdk-8u131-windows-x64.exe` file from [Oracle javase download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), I found `.rsrc/RCDATA` directory (with 7-Zip)

Comment: I downloaded that exact file today, and I get .rsrc/1033/JAVA_CAB10, with no RCDATA in the path.

Comment: @Trejkaz: For me `.rsrc/1033/JAVA_CAB10` is in a first `.rsrc\RCDATA\100` archive of `jdk-8u131-windows-x64.exe`:
`>"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x jdk-8u131-windows-x64.exe` displays `Extracting  .rsrc\RCDATA\100` and after `>"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x .rsrc\RCDATA\100` displays `Extracting  .rsrc\1033\JAVA_CAB10\111` ...

Comment: Maybe a difference between Windows and macOS builds of 7-zip? o_O

Comment: I've update with a forked version of [unpack-jdk-x64.bat](https://gist.github.com/smaudet/2cab5c8188ff0c2ae3c00bdb9499b53f) contains default 7z path, and better directory handling.

Comment: @Igor, .exe? **And what about for Mac?**

Comment: With recent JDK it is easier. You have to extract the "jdk-10.0.2_windows-x64_bin.exe" file which contain a tool.zip. Extract this one to have the portable JDK folder.

Comment: The source files packaged in the installer can be found in `C:\JDK\.rsrc\1033\JAVA_CAB9`, cd into it and `extrac32 110` and copy the resulting `src.zip` to where you need it.

Comment: There is no "tools" directory in C:\JDK\.rsrc\1033\JAVA_CAB10 after I unpacked tools.zip

Comment: @user3002512 that's because you didn't extract tools.zip into that `tools` folder. Create that folder and extract the tools.zip into it.

Comment: You can unzip [the binaries](https://github.com/adoptium/temurin8-binaries/releases/tag/jdk8u362-b09) e.g. `OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_8u362b09.zip` to `jdk-1.8.0.362.b09/` and add that as your `JAVA_HOME` path in Windows.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl If you want to use older Oracle JDK versions (not OpenJDK), they don't provide any Zip archives for Windows. This is why you have to use the above method to unpack the installer.

Answer (score 75):

- Create destination folder where you can RWX (e.g. `C:\jdk8`)
- Download jdk exe from Oracle (e.g. `jdk-8u72-windows-x64.exe`)
- Unzip the `tools.zip` found inside it into the destination folder
- In `cmd.exe`, run:

  - `cd C:\jdk8`
  - `for /r %x in (*.pack) do .\bin\unpack200 -r "%x" "%~dx%~px%~nx.jar"`

This solution works for JDK 8 too, without Admin rights.

Comment: It worked for the 64-bit version on Windows 7 on the jdk-8u31-windows-x64.

Comment: This answer allowed me to unpack JDK 8

Comment: @MarcT  running java -version still points to the old jdk. How can upate java to points to the new jdk?

Comment: @edmond You need privilege to modify the windows path (probably admin). From shell you can define your own variable (won't change the direct call to java) and you need to use as prefix. Fortunately with Eclipse you can point to any jdk on your local fs.

Comment: It seems 7-Zip unzipping JRE_xxx.exe file creates installerexe file, unzip it once more to the same folder. JDK_xxx.exe file creates tools.zip to be unzipped once more.

Comment: Small clarification: in order to extract tools.zip from exe file Far manager can be used. Its official distrib (also can be installed as a portable zip) already contains plugin arclite, which is able to extract from executable files.

Comment: Apparently Oracle changed the packaging with latest JDK8 updates (111, 112) and this trick does not work anymore :-(

Comment: Well... worked for me on 8u121 (just downloaded and did it right now). For what is worth, I downloaded the 32bits (Windows x86) package.

Comment: Well... It worked for jdk-9.0.4_windows-x64_bin.exe on Window 7 64 bit..Thanks

Comment: This also works on latest Java 7 archive jdk-7u80-windows-x64.exe

Answer (score 50):

For JDK 8u102 things have changed, this worked for me:

1. Download windows JDK exe
2. Open with 7-Zip
3. Dump contents into a directory %JDK-EXE%
4. cmd: cd %JDK-EXE%.rsrc\1033\JAVA_CAB10
5. cmd: extrac32 111
6. Now have a tools.zip in directory, open it in 7-Zip
7. Extract contents into a new directory %JDK-VERSION%
8. cmd: cd %JDK-VERSION%
9. cmd: for /r %x in (*.pack) do .\bin\unpack200 -r "%x" "%~dx%~px%~nx.jar"
10. src.zip is in %JDK-EXE%.rsrc\1033\JAVA_CAB9\110\  - put a copy into %JDK-VERSION%

Now you are ready to go.
You might want to setup JAVA_HOME and PATH to point to your %JDK-VERSION% dir and its BIN subdir.

Comment: If the above is too much like hard work, you could also try https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/jdkportable

Comment: this guy needs a medal that built this portable package

Comment: I make a small tool to automate the above process: https://github.com/kbridge/jix

Answer (score 29):

Here is a good, but a little complex, way:

#### Stage 1: MSI & CAB from native installation file

1. Download the JRE or JDK from the Oracle (Sun) website. This method will work on any version and on SDK or JRE.
2. Run and wait for the installer to load. Minimize the window.
3. In Windows 7, you should browse to this location:

   C:\Users\ **YOUR_USER_NAME** \AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java
4. There, you will have a few MSI and CAB files.

[image]

#### Stage 2: easily extract the MSI & CAB using *uniextract*

5. Browse to [Universal Extractor | LegRoom.net](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract) and download **[UniExtract Binary Archive](http://legroom.net/scripts/download.php?file=uniextract161_noinst)**.
6. Use WinRar or any un-RAR program available to you, and extract **uniextract161_noinst.rar** anywhere.

[image]

#### Stage 3: finally, extract the inner container named *core.zip*

7. Drag & drop **jdk1.6.0_31.msi** or **jre1.6.0_31.msi** on the icon of **UniExtract.exe**.
8. Select "Extract Method: MSI Administrative Installer". Wait for the process to finish.
9. Enter the new created folder.

   *If you've drag-and-dropped **jre1.6.0_31.msi** you should have a **jre1.6.0_31** folder*
10. Follow all levels inside and you'll see **core.zip**.
    [image]
11. This is what you are after. You can just unzip it anywhere and you'll have the content of the Java runtime or SDK without installing anything on your system.

#### * You can now close the installer of Java you've left opened in stage 1 *

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me I am trying to get 6.45x64 of Java under windows 7 I get a Internal Error 2203 any ideas?

Comment: I think my problem was something to do with it being an online installer. I found an older (x86) version that was an offline installer and it seems to give me the core.zip

Comment: Still can't seem to get it to work on JDK though...

Comment: @Jackie you should use full (also known as 'offline') version.

Comment: For me core.zip seemed to be tools.zip For JDK 8

Comment: I can't find any msi or cab files....

Comment: Hey @Stardust you can also start the Java installer of your choice, no need to complete the installation or even click a button, the setup files (MSI) will be placed under your "temporary files" folder, which you can access by pressing [WINDOWS]+[R] -> paste: `%TEMP%` -> [ENTER]. keep in mind there are a lot of files there, sort them by date of modification, it can be either under the root or in a sub folder, once you've copied the MSI file(s), you can cancel the installation, so essentially nothing is written to your file-system, or registry, the only purpose of it is the extraction.. enjoy.

Comment: @EladKarako Does this require admin rights? I tried it and I couldn't find any MSI files.

Comment: @Stardust probably..

Answer (score 27):

The answer has been given before. It  works for "jdk-8u91-windows-x64.exe" also

1. Unzip with 7-zip, so we get tools.zip
2. Unzip tools.zip to a folder ***folder_name*** so we get the contents in the picture
   [image]
3. In cmd move to the folder ***folder_name/bin*** and run the command

   java -version

the output will be

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

this indicates that there is something messing. Actually we need to unpack all packages.

4. In cmd move to the folder ***folder_name*** and automatically do the unpacking by executing the command

   for /r %x in (*.pack) do .\bin\unpack200 -r "%x" "%~dx%~px%~nx.jar"
5. Do step 3 again, if you get the output bellow, then the JDK is ready to use.

---

```
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b15, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Awesome. You made my day. Worked like charm. This is precise answer for OP's question. Thanks a lot for detailed instructions :)

Comment: This helped me a great deal - I just followed these steps to get a "portable" JRE 6u45 64-bit for testing old things. :)

Comment: Thanks man. It worked for "jdk-8u102-windows-i586.exe" also.

Answer (score 24):

This is how I do it,

Start with the exe installation and wait for the below screen,

[image]

Go to the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java` and copy your JDK to another place.

Cancel the installation by clicking 'x' and uninstall JDK.

Copy the copied JDK back into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java` or other folder of your choice

Comment: Somehow people missed this gem. It works!

Comment: Note to self: even after cancelling installation, i had to remove/uninstall it using Control Panel | Programs and Features.
This solution should be higher in the list, it is quick, simple and works.

Comment: Not useful when you don't have the administrator privileges on the machine

Comment: That is what I do.  Install, copy, uninstall.  I do not want Java interacting with my browser!  Stupid that we have to jump through these hoops.  And also always need to manually set JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 8):

The widely-upvoted answer is fine, I've used it for quite some time in the form of this bat file:

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET ROOT=%cd%

REM Get the tools.zip from the innards of the installer
7z e *.exe .rsrc/1033/JAVA_CAB10/111
7z e 111 7z x tools.zip
REM Extract all
7z x -aoa tools.zip -ojdk

del tools.zip
del 111

REM Searching directory structure from root for subfolders and zipfiles.
FOR /F "delims==" %%d IN ('dir /ogne /ad /b /s "%ROOT%"') DO (
    echo Descending into %%d
    FOR /F "delims==" %%f IN ('dir /b "%%d\*.pack"') DO (
        echo Extracting "%%d\%%f"
        REM Extract all packs into jars.
        jdk\bin\unpack200 -r  "%%d\%%f" "%%d\%%~nf.jar"
    )
)

ENDLOCAL
pause;
```

It requires access on the path to 7zip, and must be run in a folder alongside the JDK of your choice (it'll find it because of the *.exe up here).

Works on 8u144, and I guess it worked from the 8u20 thing.

Comment: If you want the source archive as well, you can add `7z e *.exe .rsrc/1033/JAVA_CAB9/110` and `7z e 110 7z x src.zip`

Comment: You are my Hero! Wish I could upvote more than once. I mean, all the other answers are fine, but this is a one click copy and paste solution :-)

Comment: Worked nicely for 8u201. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## Download JAVA SE with JDK

1. **Download jdk from Oracle website**: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
2. **Unzip the exe**. For example: *jdk-8u5-windows-x64.exe*
3. **Unzip the following file**: *tools.zip* (found under the unzipped folder) **to the desired JAVA_HOME**.
4. **Update the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to your desired path**.

Tested for version: jdk-7u60-windows-x64.exe, jdk-7u60-windows-x64.exe

## Download JAVA EE with JDK

1. **Download jdk from Oracle website**: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html
2. **Unzip the exe**. For example: *jdk-7u55-windows-x64.exe*
3. **Unzip the following file**: *Product\Packages\jdk.zip* (found under the unzipped folder) **to the desired JAVA_HOME**.
4. **Update the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to your desired path**.

Tested for version: jdk-7u55-windows-x64.exe

Comment: With jdk-7u60, after I unzip (step 2) with 7zip, I only get tools.zip, no other files are extracted from the exe... :(

Comment: Actually for me the same happens for jdk-7u55, for both x64 and x32...

Comment: You are trying to download the Java SE Development Kit, not the Java EE Development Kit. For Java SE JDK, Just unzip the tools.zip file to a JAVA_HOME folder. See the updated instructions above.

Comment: i extracted tools.zip and set JAVA_HOME. After I am getting "java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object" while running `javac`.

Comment: I extracted something like jdk, but intellij idea didn't recognize it as jdk home.

Comment: @arulraj.net What i did was follow Igor guide (scroll up) after extracting executing the following command within the jdk folder as he specified `for /r %x in (*.pack) do .\bin\unpack200 -r "%x" "%~dx%~px%~nx.jar"`

Comment: @Schippie Thanks. I was followed this https://gist.github.com/helkhalfi/f7e35f5302b2be7e29b4 tutorial and solved the problem.

Answer (score 7):

There is a .tar.gz file of the **Java Runtime Environment (JRE)** on the Oracle website for these operations systems: Windows x86, Windows x64, Linux x86, Linux x64, Mac OS X x64,  Solaris x64.
See: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

Also there is the **Java Development Kit (JDK)**: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html.
The Windows .tar.gz. is missing, but you can just extract the .exe file with a tool like 7zip.

I found this is very useful to make Eclipse portable. ;-)

Comment: JDK .tar.gz is missing for OSX too.

Comment: Unzipping the Windows .exe doesn't give you the files in the format you need (at least not as of 8u181). Other answers provide detailed steps on how to further extract the contents.

Answer (score 7):

You can [download](http://www.azulsystems.com/products/zulu/downloads) a portable [Zulu](http://www.azulsystems.com/products/zulu) .zip archive from Azul Systems, which are builds of OpenJDK for Windows, Linux (RHEL, SUSE, Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS) and Mac OS X.

> Zulu is a certified build of OpenJDK that is fully compliant with the Java SE standard. Zulu is 100% open source and freely downloadable. Now Java developers, system administrators and end users can enjoy the full benefits of open source Java with deployment flexibility and control over upgrade timing.

More technical information on different JVMs (including Zulu) with their architectures and OS support [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_virtual_machines).

Comment: This has zip files for Mac as well as Windows and Linux. Very nice!

Answer (score 5):

try this:
http://maven.nuiton.org/nexus/content/repositories/jvm/com/oracle/jre/

this link contains portable zip distributions for all versions.

Comment: seems like it's jre only?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link for JDK 5 zip file.
[sun-jdk-5-win32-x86-1.5.0.12.zip](http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_easyeclipse/downloads/Sun%20JREs%20and%20JDKs/1.5.0.12%20for%20EasyEclipse/sun-jdk-5-win32-x86-1.5.0.12.zip/)

Comment: Saved the day for me, thanks a bunch! Side note: sourceforge.jp has a seriously ghetto download page.

Answer (score 4):

Download the Processing application from http://www.processing.org/download/. The zip file contains a folder called java. It includes the JDK 1.6.0_32 (version checked on 19/02/2013).

Comment: As of today, the 32bit windows version contains the JRE **`1.7.0_40`**.

Comment: How can I add the processing java folder to eclipse?

Comment: @mrsquad Open Preferences dialog in Window -> Preferences menu (or Eclipse -> Preferences menu on mac), go to Java -> Installed JREs and click Add.

Comment: Checked: 2015-11-30, version there: 1.8.0_51

Comment: This is a jre, not a jdk?

Comment: It's best to get Java from Oracle directly, no telling what has been modified in a version that is included with another application.

Answer (score 4):

## OSX Instructions

Tested with `jdk-8u74-macosx-x64.dmg`.

1. Download from Oracle the `.dmg`
2. Mount the disk image
3. **Extract** the `.pkg`, dragging it. Do not double-click (it will install).
4. Open a terminal and `cd` into the package.
5. `mkdir jdk-$version && cd jdk-$version`
6. `xar -xf ../JDK*.pkg`
7. `cd jdk`<kbd>TAB</kbd>
8. `tar zxf Payload`
9. The `Contents/Home` folder contains the JDK

Comment: This is indeed the best solution for mac! Just a note, to access the folder `Contents/Home` from Finder, rename the `jdk TAB` file (from step 7) to remove the `.pkg` extension and make it a Finder accessible folder

Answer (score 4):

You can download SEVER JRE it contains jdk. [server jre 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre7-downloads-1931105.html)

1. Download server-jre-< version>.tar.gz file for windows system.
2. If you have 7zip tar file can be extracted by that, I used cygwin(cygwin can be installed without admin rights see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538695/manual-cygwin-installation-without-using-setup-exe)) to extract tar file with command `tar xzvf file.tar.gz` any other tar extractor will also work

Now extracted JDK folder will be created in same folder.

Comment: Works even for jdk8 as well. You made my day. This is by far the easiest method.

Comment: +1. This works for Oracle JDK 7 downloaded from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase7-archive-downloads.html.
Download the server JRE. Untar it. Voila!

Answer (score 3):

The Sun JVM is available as a MSI which is executable from a script.

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/install-msi.html

Comment: that's one step closer to what I'm looking for...

Comment: Switch to Ubuntu.  "sudo apt-get sun-java6-sdk" ...  (The very first time you have to accept a license).

Comment: I've already switched to ubuntu, and even there, I rather just download and untar from oracle than issuing apt-get, with just a symlink I can have many JDK installed side by side...

Comment: You cannot get the "download and unzip and run" functionality easily because you need to accept the license.  I have, however, found that Jenkins can automatically download Java and make it available to itself.  Perhaps you could lift that functionality for yourself?

Comment: This no longer works.  The download link has been taken down.

Answer (score 3):

```
mkdir c:\JDK
cd c:\JDK
git clone https://bitbucket.org/ramazanpolat/jdk-8u112-windows-x64/
```

or

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/ramazanpolat/jdk-8u112-windows-x86
```

Answer (score 3):

JDK's can be downloaded from here as zip file nor .exe
http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/java/

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for asking; the JDK does not seem to interact with the Windows registry.

However, the JRE does in certain instances.

Link: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0604.html

Comment: well it certainly does now. i have not been able to re-install jdk6 due to the registry config being broken and it insisting on a reinstall which never works

Comment: well, that's the sort of things I'm trying to avoid...

Answer (score 2):

The Process described by Igor and CharlesB Works to me, since IDE's like NetBeans and Eclipse permit specify the location of the JDK, even software like Apache Tomcat (the ZIP Distribution) use BASH - FILES to set it up (then specify the JDK location using relatives URI).
I Have a USB-HardDisk With NetBeans, Eclipse, Apache Tomcat working with a JDK in "portable mode".
I Had a way to extract a copy of the JDK from the installers files: Install it, Copy it in other place and then uninstall it. A dirty way to extract it, but was successfull.
The place to put EXTRA - LIBS was: %PLACE_WHERE_JDK_ARE%\jre\lib\ext

Answer (score 2):

You can just use 7zip (or another similar app) to get the dirs inside the core.zip file that's bundled in the installer.
Just use 7zip to browse the exe, you'll see a core.zip file which has all the files that usually go inside "jreX" dir (where X is the major version number).
As for setting env variables and the such, you can follow the other answers. If all you want is a portable jre (for example, you can run your jars by using java.exe jarfile or javaw.exe jarfile) then this solution will do.
This is very similar to copying the jre dir from one place to another

Comment: Not helping ...Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object

Answer (score 2):

This link

http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

helps you at least avoid the obnoxious preload installer getting straight to the SDK.

From there, I would install this in a throw-away VM, on your old crufty PC or elsewhere, then transfer the resulting

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
```

(or similar) to your new machine, set the very few usual ENV variables, and there you ideally go, w/o all the marketing junk and potential tie-ins. Of course, also w/o the security from frequent automatic updates.

Comment: Also without browser plugins so applets and javafx are not going to work, webstart is not available, the jar type is not bound to javaw.exe and no "default java" is installed at all. But if you don't need any of that, of course this is just fine.

Comment: Yep, I couldn't agree more :-) That's what the OP "no installer" asked for. Of course, someone (certainly not from sun-oracle) could analyse what happens to the registry during a regular install and provide a number of .reg(istry) files on a take-it-or-leave-it basis. As we know, many browsers disabled any and all java-plugins. For good reasons. I am glad, they did.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered you can run the installer in Wine. This works:

`WINEPREFIX=/home/jason/java wine jre-7u11-windows-i586.exe`

Then once it is finished you can just zip up the `/home/jason/java/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Java/jre7/`

This should work for jdk as well

Answer (score 1):

I did copy the JRE folder several times and it always works fine. But I am really not sure if you can just get a zip file with its contents, as the official installation install the plugins for IE, Firefox and whatsoever.

Comment: well, I have a zip file uploaded to dropbox, I download it and copy to every machine... it worked fine so far...

Answer (score 1):

http://androidhost.org/D8wsv

You can get jre-7u75-windows-i586.zip from the link above.

Answer (score 1):

Commands from tips below wrapped as batch script. Save this as unpack.bat. Then place it to dir with jdk/jre extracted files.

```
@echo off

cd /d "%~dp0"
for /r %%x in (*.pack) do .\bin\unpack200 -r "%%x" "%%~dx%%~px%%~nx.jar"
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed JDK 8 with the exe installer and then uninstalled JRE, I now have JDK folder with no env variable or other setting changed.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

Here's where. Download the .gz package.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: The OP specifically asked for how to download a .zip, but this solution specifically suggests downloading a .gz (slightly different), which is not extractable on a native (only built-in utilities) Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Install in **sandbox**, and copy the folder out.