# Java JDK install unzip version

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [where can I get the latest JRE / JDK as a zip file, I mean, no exe installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619662/where-can-i-get-the-latest-jre-jdk-as-a-zip-file-i-mean-no-exe-installer)

Does the Java JDK binary image come in a format which can be just unzipped in a certain folder (i.e. without using an installer)

Comment: Doesn't it come with an option to extract files? Did you check command line arguments? Btw What OS? Windows or *nix?

Comment: @PeterLawrey not true. Many times the installer simply unzips it into a directory and creates shortcuts to the start menu and/or maybe the desktop.

Comment: I just downloaded jdk-7u80-windows-x64.exe and could open it on 7-Zip by right-clicking on it and selectiong "Open compressed...". I see a tools.zip in there and once you open it, you see the usual directory structure and files, which you can extract wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux the self-extracting Installer doesn't do any real "installation" in the sense that it modifies the system, it simple unpacks itself to a subdirectory of the current directory (and fixes up some `.jar` files).

If you want to redistribute the JDK (or JRE), then you can do so, provided you follow [the requirements in the README file](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/readme-142177.html#redistribution). For this you'll build your own packages (i.e. zip the appropriate files of your local installation).