# OpenJDK availability for Windows OS

Tags: java, windows

Are there any OpenJDK installers available for Windows, possibly with free updates for a longer time than Oracle offers? The OpenJDK home page (http://openjdk.java.net/) offers only ZIP files.

Comment: Perhaps the Oracle distribution is the best place to start for a newbie. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html This is based on OpenJDK and the differences are fairly obscure.

Comment: It may be important to note the different licensing terms for the OpenJDK and the Oracle distribution. The Oracle distribution is only licensed for use on a general purpose computer. Should you be targeting an embedded device then you need to negotiate a license with Oracle for which I presume they expect money.

Comment: At least Oracle, Azul and Redhat offer OpenJDK builds on Windows. The later even wie Icetea.

Comment: I really don't think that the recommendations rule applies to such a specific question? There doesn't seem to be a lot of scope for opinion here: "Is it OpenJDK?", "Is it for Windows?", and "Can I download it?" all seem like pretty clear conditions, and we're obviously talking about prebuilt binaries because the question already links to build instructions...

Comment: They're linked on the github page here: https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild

Comment: For the latest public version of the Oracle JDK 1.7 (Update 80), here's a working link: https://archive.org/download/jdk-7u80-windows-x64_201809/jdk-7u80-windows-x64.exe I've verified that this binary is legit and matches the one available directly from Oracle (after you go through their silly sign-up and account creation). Trust me, I'm a guy on the Internet.

Comment: http://jdk.java.net/archive/

Answer (score 194):

You may find OpenJDK 6 and 7 binaries for Windows in [openjdk-unofficial-builds](https://github.com/alexkasko/openjdk-unofficial-builds#openjdk-unofficial-installers-for-windows-linux-and-mac-os-x) github project.

Update: OpenJDK 8 and 11 LTS binaries for Windows x86_64 can be found in [ojdkbuild](https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild) github project.

Disclaimer: I've built them myself.

Update (2019): OpenJDK Updates Project Builds for 8 and 11 [are available now](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk8u-dev/2019-April/009105.html).

Comment: +1 ! excuse me if I ask, but is there a reason that are the binaries hosted on bitbucket if the code seems to be on github?

Comment: @naxa github closed downloads section soon after the first release of these builds. And there is a full project mirror on bitbucket, not only binaries.

Comment: @alexkasko, Project is discontinued?

Comment: @Pacerier, 6 and 7 builds are discontinued, 8 and 9 (in ojdkbuild repo) are active

Comment: @alexkasko, btw doesn't Oracle already release those builds too on its main site?

Comment: I'm downvoting this. Nothing personal, but an OpenJDK build built by someone on the internet cannot easily be trusted. Who is this ojdkbuild entity anyway? How do I know I'm not distributing malware?

Comment: @LukasEder, no offense taken, I work on jdk-windows builds at Red Hat, jdk builds distributed on developers.redhat.com are based on ojdkbuild. For possible follow-up questions about ojdkbuild project please open an issue on github or post to ojdkuild maillist - I'll comment there.

Comment: @alexkasko: That's cool. After some research, I've noticed that you're working for Red Hat, but I really wish something a tad more official would show up first on Google, rather than an individual's effort. Perhaps, that `ojdkbuild` github page and group could also look a bit more official. I'll definitely create an issue tomorrow

Answer (score 55):

In case you are still looking for a Windows build of OpenJDK, Azul Systems launched the Zulu product line last fall. The Zulu distribution of OpenJDK is built and tested on Windows and Linux. We posted the OpenJDK 8 version this week, though OpenJDK 7 and 6 are both available too. The following URL leads to you free downloads, the Zulu community forum, and other details:
http://www.azulsystems.com/products/zulu
These are binary downloads, so you do not need to build OpenJDK from scratch to use them.

I can attest that building OpenJDK 6 for Windows was not a trivial exercise. Of the six different platforms we've built (OpenJDK6, OpenJDK7, and OpenJDK8, each for Windows and Linux) for x64 so far, the Windows OpenJDK6 build took by far the most effort to wring out items that didn't work on Windows, or would not pass the Technical Compatibility Kit test protocol for Java SE 6 "as is."

Disclaimer: I am the Product Manager for Zulu. You can review my Zulu release notices here:
https://support.azulsystems.com/hc/communities/public/topics/200063190-Zulu-Releases
I hope this helps.

Comment: Are you planning to add support for JavaFX in any future releases of your product?

Comment: JavaFX has not been formally lodged as a request in the Zulu forum yet. There have been a few people casually interested in FX, though no formal request tickets yet.

Comment: I see. Well, then maybe I will make it a formal request in the future, who knows? :P
Thanks for the response! :]

Comment: There are only 64 bit builds for Windows. Are 32 bit builds for windows somewhere on your roadmap or are there no plans ?

Comment: @MattSchuetze : Do you have a Server OpenJRE for windows (as opposed to the default client OpenJRE) ?

Comment: @anjanb The Zulu Community builds for 64-bit Intel are all server builds.

Comment: As a bit of an update, Azul now posts all of the Zulu community JDK images on the Zulu community web site: http://zulu.org/download/. Anyone -- like @benohead -- interested in 32-bit targets for Intel and now ARM can learn more about the Zulu Embedded product family: https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-embedded/ . These images are created to your specs, so could be server, client, or both, plus choice of JRE, JDK, or compact profile.

Comment: @MattSchuetze : Oracle ships with multiple java binaries 1) jdk 2) client JRE 3) server JRE. I was asking about #3 Server JRE. It appears that zulu doesn't have a server JRE.

Comment: @MattSchuetze, link https://support.azulsystems.com/hc/communities/public/topics/200063190-Zulu-Releases is down....

Comment: The public release announcement now live on http://zulu.org/forum/. Please use that URL to review all Zulu release notices going forward. Thanks.

Comment: @MattSchuetze, Ok.

Comment: @MattSchuetze, With Oracle now releasing the binary builds of Java 9 and up, is there still any point in this?

Comment: @Pacerier, we still see demand for an alternative vendor, professionally supported OpenJDK distribution that passes all TCK certification criteria. Our latest Zulu release offers ARM v8 64-bit support, so there is breadth and depth--way beyond the original Windows question asked here--that Azul aims to cover in the Zulu product line. Hope this helps.

Comment: @MattSchuetze, But since Oracle does well, and is **free in both price and licensing**, exactly why would anyone want the alternative for?

Comment: Vendor diversity. Covering niches the larger vendor won't explore. Nimble reaction times. Sticking it to The Man. I'm sure there are lots of other reasons that ultimately come down to personal preference. Java is not as fungible as other commodities (like say gasoline or salt) so consumer choice still plays a factor. BTW, I'm still a big fan of Oracle and the work they do in the open in the Java community remains technically outstanding. Though if you extend your reasoning to say Linux, then we wouldn't need CentOS and Ubutntu and Debian and Alpine and Gentoo. Yet we have them and more.

Answer (score 20):

For Java 12 onwards, official General-Availability (GA) and Early-Access (EA) Windows 64-bit builds of the OpenJDK (GPL2 + Classpath Exception) from Oracle are available as tar.gz/zip from the [JDK website](https://jdk.java.net).

If you prefer an installer, there are several distributions. There is a [public Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nFGazvrCvHMZJgFstlbzoHjpAVwv5DEdnaBr_5pKuHo/edit?usp=sharing) and [Blog post](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-2-0-0-6b9aa8d6d244) by the Java Champions community which lists the best-supported OpenJDK distributions. Currently, these are:

- [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) has been superseded by Adoptium/Temurin (Hotspot) and IBM Semeru (OpenJ9)
- [Adoptium Temurin](https://adoptium.net)
- [Amazon Corretto](https://aws.amazon.com/de/corretto)
- [IBM Semeru](https://developer.ibm.com/languages/java/semeru-runtimes/) (with OpenJ9 JVM)
- Liberica from [Bellsoft](https://bell-sw.com)
- [Microsoft Build of OpenJDK](https://www.microsoft.com/openjdk)
- [OpenLogic OpenJDK](https://www.openlogic.com/openjdk-downloads)
- [Red Hat OpenJDK](https://developers.redhat.com/products/openjdk)
- [SAPMachine](https://github.com/SAP/SapMachine/releases) (backed by SAP)
- [Zulu Community](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community) (backed by Azul Systems)

Comment: https://jdk.java.net/archive/ link is more relevant now.

Comment: Worth mentioning that AdoptOpenJDK is moving to the Eclipse Foundation under the name of Adoptium. See https://blog.adoptopenjdk.net/2020/06/adoptopenjdk-to-join-the-eclipse-foundation.

Comment: Thing is, for some reason this question was closed a year ago and a newer duplicate was kept open: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52511778/how-to-install-openjdk-11-on-windows/67103552

Answer (score 16):

I recently came across this site: https://adoptopenjdk.net/

Seems reliable to me. Haven't tried myself but surely will give it a try.

License:

> License(s)
>   Build scripts and other code to produce the binaries, the website and other build infrastructure are licensed under Apache License, Version 2.0. OpenJDK code itself is licensed under GPL v2 with Classpath Exception.

EDIT:
I was also delighted to learn that AdoptOpenJDK MSI installer (JDK and JRE) now comes with IcedTeaWeb, which is a replacement for Oracle WebStart - simple installer with almost 'next-next-next-finish' and the JWS applications works like they used to.

Answer (score 12):

Red Hat announces they will distribute an OpenJDK for Windows platform:
http://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/06/27/openjdk-now-available-for-windows/

EDITED (thx to CaseyB comment): there is no PRODUCTION support on Windows. From the documentation:

> All Red Hat distributions of OpenJDK 8 on Windows are supported for development of applications that work in conjunction with JBoss Middleware, so that you have the convenience and confidence to develop and test in Windows or Linux-based environments and deploy your solution to a 100% compatible, fully supported, OpenJDK 8 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

- https://developers.redhat.com/products/openjdk/overview/
- https://developers.redhat.com/terms-and-conditions/

Comment: Red Hat's license states that the services are for "development purposes only" and that `using the services provided under the Program for a production installation` is a violation of the terms.
So presumably we can't distribute this installer to our paying customers or even have them install it themselves for production purposes? [Read here](https://developers.redhat.com/terms-and-conditions/). The GitHub binaries seem to have much clearer terms.

Comment: @CaseyB. Good to know. I will amend my answer for people who doesn't read comment. But when I read https://developers.redhat.com/products/openjdk/overview/, I don't see if we HAVE to subscribe to the Red Hat's Developer Program (so I am not sure if there is a violation). But obviously there is no support for production on Windows.

Comment: https://developers.redhat.com/products/openjdk/download/

The windows installers are available for download now.

Comment: Redhat can’t restrict the distribution of Apple code in that way.

Comment: It's not opensource (free), right?

Answer (score 6):

OpenSCG maintains [OpenJDK 6 installers](http://www.openscg.com/se/openjdk/) for 32-bit Windows and other operating systems.

To configure it, create a JAVA_HOME environment variable and set it to C:\OpenSCG\openjdk-6.0.24 or whatever is the current version. Then add %JAVA_HOME%\bin; to the beginning of your PATH environment variable.

You can edit your environment variables by contextual clicking (My) Computer, selecting Properties, clicking Advanced system settings if you’re in Windows 7, clicking the Advanced tab and then clicking Environment Variables.

Comment: Does this support graphical applications or is it command line only?

Comment: Site no longer exists

Answer (score 5):

Only [OpenJDK 7](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/jdk7/binaries/index.html). OpenJDK6 is basically the same code base as SUN's version, that's why it redirects you to the official Oracle site.

Comment: I wonder **why** there are no OpenJDK 6 binary downloads for Windows. Granted: The Oracle JDK is *mostly* the same thing, but the same thing can be said for Linux and Solaris: they are *mostly* the same thing, why provide OpenJDK binaries for those platforms, then?

Comment: I can't find the OpenJDK Binaries anymore. Anybody has an idea if and where one can find them?

Comment: @eckes http://www.java7developer.com/blog/?p=55 seems to indicate (in the comments at the end) to go back to the Oracle website...

Comment: @VonC I actually found a official compile from Sun, the RI of Java SE 7. However they claim they will not update it: http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/promoted/b146/jcp_bcl/

Comment: @eckes: very interesting. I have updated http://stackoverflow.com/a/9113640/6309 accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the thoroughly tested OpenJDK releases provided by Oracle at http://jdk.java.net .

For example, ready to use builds of OpenJDK 10.0.2 from Oracle for 64-bit Linux, MacOS and Windows can be found at http://jdk.java.net/10/ .

Comment: The proper link is https://jdk.java.net/archive/ now.

Answer (score 4):

An interesting alternative with long term support is [Corretto](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/). It was anounced by [James Gosling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=148&v=WuZk23O76Zk) on DevOXX recently. It is a no-cost, multiplatform, production-ready distribution of the Open Java Development Kit (OpenJDK). Corretto comes with long-term support that will include performance enhancements and security fixes. Currently it provides Java Versions 8 and 11 (12 soon) and you can download binaries for all major platforms

- Linux
- Microsoft Windows
- macOS
- Docker

And the second interesting alternative is [Dragonwell](https://github.com/alibaba/dragonwell8) provided by Alibaba. It is a friendly fork but they want to upstream their changes into the openjdk repo regularily... They currently offer Java8 but the have [interesting](https://github.com/alibaba/dragonwell8/wiki/Alibaba-Dragonwell8-Release-Notes) things like a backported Flight Recorder (from 11 to 8) ...

And thirdly as already mentioned by others the [adoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) initivative is also worth looking at.

Comment: "docker"? as in, linux?

Comment: Further details can be found here: https://hub.docker.com/_/amazoncorretto

Comment: sigh. no, i know what docker is, but "docker" is not an operating system. your list makes no sense, it would be like if you said "linux, microsoft windows, macOS, apt"

Comment: sigh, too. Perfect so we both know what docker is. But if you read carefully you would see that I didn't write OS but platform. And docker is the leading container platform... Case solved.

Answer (score 0):

Found all the windows binaries here :

https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild

These Windows binaries are built to keep them as close as possible in behaviour to java-x-openjdk CentOS packages.

Comment: this is already described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991508/openjdk-availability-for-windows-os/13801660#13801660

Answer (score 0):

You can go to AdoptOpenJDK to download your binaries for all platforms provided by a great community.

Comment: downvoting cause it's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991508/openjdk-availability-for-windows-os/54195622#54195622 duplicate