# Intellij can't compile JSP- Error: PWC6345

Tags: java, jsp, ide, intellij-idea

I'm having a problem with my web application in INTELLIJ. I'm new to INTELLIJ so I dont really know how to fix this. Others IDEs had nevere such a problem.

When I'm trying to run my web application it gets me this error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac. A full JDK (not just JRE) is required
```

The JDK is chosen and glassfish is working. Others had the same problem, some fixed it with a change in config file of glassfish. But that didnt fix my problem.

Does someone actually know how I can fix that and be able to run my web applications in INTELLIJ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: File -> Project Structure -> SDKs (in list) -> Add the path to your JDK (e.g., /path/to/x86/java/jdk1.6.0.35) and not a JRE.  The JRE only contains the things necessary to run Java programs. The JDK contains code necessary to compile and debug programs.

Comment: Already added:
![jdk](http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/9863/fac5bd58dc0f4739ad5cab9.png) error still there :/

Comment: Hmm. Try the solution found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113346/pwc6345-there-is-an-error-in-invoking-javac-error-when-using-jetty-wtp-plugi . From your screenshot, it appears that you are doing the right thing, but can you show what is says under SDKs?

Comment: Problem with that is, that it is for an eclipse extension and not specific for INTELLIJ

Comment: The system property being set is used by Jasper, and not Eclipse. It happens that that person is an Eclipse developer. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-23098

Comment: Really dont know how I should use that for IntelliJ & glassfish. Proably I should go back to netbeans :x

Comment: As a Netbeans convert myself, IntelliJ is far superior in my opinion. This issue needs to be corrected, as others will face the same quirkiness in your development team.  I'm surprised that it's happening actually because usually Glassfish and IntelliJ "just work" together.  It definitely seems like a configuration issue. How did you configure Glassfish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glassfish is using `JAVA_HOME` environment variable and starts under the JDK defined by this variable. On your system this variable may point to the JRE instead. You can either change it in the system settings or directly in IntelliJ IDEA (repeat the same for Debug):

[image]

Comment: That fixed it thanks! It's the only solution on the internet that actually works for this specific problem! Thank you very much!