# Servlet filter in Jetty

Tags: web-applications, jetty, servlet-filters, embedded-jetty

I've added a Servlet Filter in the web.xml of my web-app. It is supposed to just intercept some calls and redirect them . When launching the Jetty server I can see that my filter is being initialized since the function `public void init(final FilterConfig config)` is being called.
However when sending requests from a browser I get the following exception

```
PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required
```

I'm using eclipse with Jdk 7 configured and Jetty 8.12. Any indications to what I can do in getting away from this ?  Below is the stacktrace

```
Caused by:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:119)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Jsr199JavaCompiler.compile(Jsr199JavaCompiler.java:208)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:384)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:453)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.loadTagFile(JspServletWrapper.java:280)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.loadTagFile(TagFileProcessor.java:660)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.access$000(TagFileProcessor.java:91)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor$TagFileLoaderVisitor.visit(TagFileProcessor.java:719)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1502)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2297)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2347)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:499)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2297)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2347)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2371)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$IncludeDirective.accept(Node.java:648)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2297)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2347)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:499)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2297)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.loadTagFiles(TagFileProcessor.java:737)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:235)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:890)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:944)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: In other words ... When you remove the servlet filter, this exception doesn't occur? Sorry, but I can't believe this. This exception is thrown far beyond the call of the servlet filter. You would have had exactly the same problem when requesting the deisred JSP directly without using a servlet filter. Please rephrase the question accordingly.

Comment: refer this it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113346/pwc6345-there-is-an-error-in-invoking-javac-error-when-using-jetty-wtp-plugi

Comment: Try it again after changing the JRE to JDK. Right click on the `Project -> Java Build Path -> Library -> JRE System Library`. Click on `Add Library` and select `JRE System Library` and add location of JDK. delete previous one and selected JDK to make it default.