# jackrabbit - There is an error in invoking javac. A full JDK (not just JRE) is required

Tags: jcr, jackrabbit

I'm learning Jackrabbit and following the [documentation](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/standalone-server.html) to run a standalone server. When I run the command `java -jar jackrabbit-standalone-2.16.2.jar` and access `localhost:8080` on my browser, I get a 500 error saying:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I have set my `jdk/bin` path in my environment variables.Also, my javac command is working properly. I've jdk version 1.8.0_74 and Jackrabbit version 2.16.2

Edit: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15444615/6921630) answer, I tried setting my jdk to my `installed jres` in eclipse but that didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Running the latest jackarabit standalone jar(2.17.3) in my machine(windows 10 and java home pointing in java8 jdk) produced the same errors.

I then executed the rar with `java -Djava.home="%JAVA_HOME%" -jar jackrabbit-standalone-2.17.3.jar`. Although I got the same error in browser I was able to see errors in the console where I invoked the running command.

One of these error was 
`can't open C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\lib\tzmappings`.

Searching my java installation I found that the missing files, are located under `jre`'s installation folder.

So I eventually made the standalone jar to work with:
`java -Djava.home="%JAVA_HOME%\jre" -jar jackrabbit-standalone-2.17.3.jar`

The initial error is a bit misleading as it refers to javac and not to the missing files.

The whole thing seems to be a bug for me. Please give a try to my workaround and if it works for you consider filing a bug in [Jackrabbit's issue tracker platform](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/JCR/issues/JCR-4308?filter=allopenissues).

Answer (score 1):

`jackrabbit-standalone` uses JSP. JSP needs compilation. Compilation needs JDK.

Before running `java -jar jackrabbit-standalone-2.16.2.jar` do you check your `JAVA_HOME`, and make sure it refers to a fully-fledged JDK? In short, the `bin` directory should have `javac`.

Comment: ...I've checked, my `java_home` points to my jdk folder..I've set all my environment variables according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26640589/6921630) answer

Answer (score 1):

I found that there was another variable in the `Path` environment System variable preceding my `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` variable.

You don't have to delete the other variable, but move it down (or move `%JAVA_HOME\bin` up) to correct the load order.