# OpenJDK Windows Distribution

Tags: windows, java

Does anyone know of a OpenJDK distribution for Windows? Specifically, I am looking for JDK 8 32 bit. I found 64-bit distribution:
http://www.azulsystems.com/products/zulu

but I really need 32 bit.

Comment: use this page JDK8 https://jdk8.java.net/download.html and JDK7 https://jdk7.java.net/download.html

Comment: The key for me is OpenJDK. Those are bound by an Oracle Early Adopter License. I am looking for open source Java.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenJDK availability for Windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991508/openjdk-availability-for-windows-os)

Answer (score 6):

MonkBen and others:

Thank you for highlighting the Zulu OpenJDK offering. You are correct that Azul only has 64-bit JDK 8, 7, and 6 distributions of OpenJDK available for Intel platforms today. Support for 32-bit JDKs remains an open community request.

Please review this Zulu Forum topic for more details on 32-bit support
https://support.azulsystems.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200914964-Regarding-32-bit-JDK-JRE-buildds-of-OpenJDk
Per the guidance there, you are welcome to join the Zulu forum and add your specific platform requests to that topic. We do include community requests in our roadmap activities and release planning, so the more votes for specific versions, platforms, and use cases, the better our planning.

Sincerely

Matt Schuetze

Disclaimer: I work for Azul Systems, and am the Product Manager for the Zulu product family.

Comment: Zulu does not support JavaFX though, does it?

Comment: At this point no, Zulu does not also ship JavaFX. Shall I open a request on your behalf on the Zulu new features forum?

Comment: Sure, that would be great.

Comment: @MonkBen, I added a request here: https://support.azulsystems.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201638904-Add-OpenJFX-to-Zulu so please review and add any details you feel are helpful in providing a workable JFX setup.

Comment: Any updates on this since over a year ago? Still looking for OpenJDK 8 x32. A client is planning to move to 64-bit OS as the standard image, but it'll be *years* before all the 32-bit machines are decommissioned, so I need to use 32-bit for now.

Comment: @MattSchuetze the link on Zulu Forum is broken - it would be great if you update it with - https://support.azul.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200914964-REQUEST-Regarding-32-bit-JDK-JRE-buildds-of-OpenJDk?locale=en-us

Comment: @IlyaBuziuk, the forum moved. The appropriate forum topic is now http://zulu.org/forum/thread/regarding-32-bit-jdkjre-buildds-of-openjdk/. Since this 2014 inquiry, the Zulu family expanded to offer embedded and enterprise targets not included on the community downloads. There are x86 64-bit and 32-bit build targets, both JDKs and JREs, now in inventory. They all have OpenJDK no-strings redistribution models compared to most other JVMs, though aren't available as free downloads. Please contact Azul to see what type of support plan fits your adoption and distribution needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build 32 bit OpenJDK for windows by yourself, here is the link you can get help:
http://openjdk.java.net/groups/build/

and https://github.com/alexkasko/openjdk-unofficial-builds

Answer (score 0):

## *AdoptOpenJDK*

The [*AdoptOpenJDK*](https://adoptopenjdk.net) project provides builds & installers of the [*OpenJDK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) source code. Free of cost. The project’s build & [test tools](https://blog.adoptopenjdk.net/2019/07/the-first-drop-introducing-adoptopenjdk-quality-assurance-aqa-v1-0) are open-source.

As of 2020-03, that project provides a [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) build of the *OpenJDK* implementation of [Java 8 specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) for the [Windows OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows).

Notice the search filters for *Operating System* (Windows) and for *Architecture* (x86).

[image: screenshot of web page showing a download available for x86 build of OpenJDK 8 for Windows OS]