# Java SE 8 totally crashes

Tags: java, jvm, windows-10

**How do I stop Java from crashing?**

I get the following error message:

***Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working***
A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

The problem occurs sporadically when a Java application with a GUI is running, for instance the Java Control Panel. A message box pops up, then the application terminates.

The problem seemed to disappear while running Windows 10 in safe mode. I tried installing Java in safe mode, then booting as normal, but the problem persisted.

**Other things I've tried:**

Uninstalling Java with IObit Uninstaller, and then installing it again. The following Java downloads have been tested:

- Windows x86: jdk-8u101-windows-i586.exe
- Windows x64: jdk-8u101-windows-x64.exe
- Windows x64: jdk-8u102-windows-x64.exe

Adding the following system environment variable: _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx256M

Deleting *Trace and Log Files* and *Cached Applications and Applets* from the Java Control Panel.

In the Windows Firewall, checked *Private* and *Public* for all occurrences of *Java(TM) Platform SE binary* in the list titled "Allowed apps and features:".

**Sample Windows Error Report:**

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_javaw.exe_9708089e7a83cc89d16e43ff37941a552cd90d3_7cb3547c_0dba66dc\Report.wer:

Version=1
EventType=APPCRASH
EventTime=131185375445168941
ReportType=2
Consent=1
UploadTime=131185375447679209
ReportIdentifier=a4bed1e4-7c5a-11e6-8569-f0def1d0b080
IntegratorReportIdentifier=26d0dc1e-c489-4d2e-a6fc-31c2734167ac
WOW64=1
NsAppName=javaw.exe
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Application Name
Sig[0].Value=javaw.exe
Sig[1].Name=Application Version
Sig[1].Value=8.0.1020.14
Sig[2].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[2].Value=576af2f5
Sig[3].Name=Fault Module Name
Sig[3].Value=ltc_game32-116096.dll
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[4].Value=1.0.0.1
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[5].Value=57cf4e9b
Sig[6].Name=Exception Code
Sig[6].Value=c000041d
Sig[7].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[7].Value=00002e70
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=10.0.10586.2.0.0.768.101
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1044
DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=e991
DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=e9914d83b8c1c612fa137735e40aca93
DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=a97e
DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=a97e58e24cf03b62995f64253cf6c289
UI[2]=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
UI[3]=Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working
UI[4]=Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.
UI[5]=Check online for a solution and close the program
UI[6]=Check online for a solution later and close the program
UI[7]=Close the program
LoadedModule[0]=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNEL32.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.10586.589_none_ea8aeaa1b9b5d5d4\COMCTL32.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\msvcr100.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\client\jvm.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\PSAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[19]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WS2_32.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cfgmgr32.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\verify.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\java.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\zip.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SHELL32.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\windows.storage.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\shlwapi.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\shcore.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\powrprof.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\awt.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\apphelp.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
LoadedModule[39]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSCTF.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\PROGRA~2\RAPTRI~1\PlaysTV\ltc_help32-116096.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINTRUST.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSASN1.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPT32.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\PROGRA~2\RAPTRI~1\Raptr\ltc_help32-115528.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\dwmapi.dll
LoadedModule[46]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[47]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\net.dll
LoadedModule[48]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
LoadedModule[49]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\nio.dll
LoadedModule[50]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\d3d9.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\aticfx32.dll
LoadedModule[52]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\atiu9pag.dll
LoadedModule[53]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\atiumdag.dll
LoadedModule[54]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\atiumdva.dll
LoadedModule[55]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\fontmanager.dll
LoadedModule[56]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\clbcatq.dll
LoadedModule[57]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WindowsCodecs.dll
LoadedModule[58]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\dataexchange.dll
LoadedModule[59]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\dcomp.dll
LoadedModule[60]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\d3d11.dll
LoadedModule[61]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\dxgi.dll
LoadedModule[62]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\twinapi.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[63]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\bcrypt.dll
LoadedModule[64]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\t2k.dll
LoadedModule[65]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\dcpr.dll
LoadedModule[66]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\sunec.dll
LoadedModule[67]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[68]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NSI.dll
LoadedModule[69]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
LoadedModule[70]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
LoadedModule[71]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[72]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[73]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\imagehlp.dll
LoadedModule[74]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\gpapi.dll
LoadedModule[75]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cryptnet.dll
LoadedModule[76]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINNSI.DLL
LoadedModule[77]=C:\PROGRA~2\RAPTRI~1\PlaysTV\ltc_game32-116096.dll
LoadedModule[78]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=APPCRASH
AppName=Java(TM) Platform SE binary
AppPath=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
NsPartner=windows
NsGroup=windows8
ApplicationIdentity=4BD76306D181AD1DC7F9896921FBF40E
```

**Update 20016-09-20:**

Now I've tried these:

- Zulu (zulu8.17.0.3-jdk8.0.102-win_x64.msi)
- java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.102-2.b14.ojdkbuild.windows.x86_64.zip
- java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-2.b14.windows.x86_64.zip

The last two I got from here: https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild (from this SO-page: [OpenJDK availability for Windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991508/openjdk-availability-for-windows-os))

All crashes.

The following program eventually crashes:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public Test() {
        setTitle("Java Crash Test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);
        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea()));
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new Test().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should report this to Oracle if it's not immediately related to a piece of software that you've authored.

Comment: It looks like the crash was caused by a bug in that particular program. Did you create this app? If so, show the full stack trace for the exception.

Comment: I will advise you to try install a older or earlier version of the java jdk

Comment: Where do I get an earlier version? The oldest version they have available is 8u101. Unless I go to the archive, but that requires registration (I'm not going to register).

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: The question was implied: "How do I stop Java from crashing?", or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similiar crash and when I googled for 'APPCRASH ltc_game32-116096.dll' I found that many application crash because of Plays.TV which came with a driver update from AMD.

[Uninstalling Plays.TV](http://support.raptr.com/support/solutions/articles/12000003200-how-do-i-uninstall-plays-tv) may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted Plays.TV based on this tip and it solved my JAVA issue with a TD Advanced Dashboard crashing with the message Java (TM) Web Launcher has stopped working.