# Where do I find the latest OpenJDK 8 GA build windows 10?

Tags: java

I'm trying to located the OpenJDK 8 GA build. When I navigate to https://openjdk.java.net/ a link is provided to https://jdk.java.net/11/ for the newest openJDK11 build. Once I arrive at jdk.java.net/11 on the left nav bar there is a link to jdk 8. The problem I'm seeing is version 8 is an EA build. Where do I find the latest ga build for windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenJDK availability for Windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991508/openjdk-availability-for-windows-os)

Comment: Are you looking for sources or binaries? Are you looking for the first/initial GA release or the latest update for 8?

Comment: @omajid first/initial GA release of the latest update. I just found this site https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/zulu-windows/

Comment: They're linked on the github page here: https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild

Answer (score 25, accepted):

2019-07-02 Edit: Some parts of OpenJDK provide "official" binaries now. OpenJDK 8 and 11 are available here: https://adoptopenjdk.net/upstream.html

Original Answer:

The OpenJDK project itself publishes only the source code. <strike>They do not publish binaries at all.</strike>

OpenJDK the project has some conventions that may not be obvious. For example `jdk8` is the branch where all work was done before OpenJDK 8 was released. After that, work continues in the `jdk8u` branch: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/. Each new version gets a version like 8u133, which is kind of like 8.133, if you will. The very first release of OpenJDK 8 was just `8` (or `8u0`). Newest is `8u191`.

If you want an OpenJDK build, you need to get it from somewhere other than OpenJDK. Some options (in alphabetical order):

- AdaptOpenJDK: https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html#x64_win (8u181, 3 months old)
- Azul: https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/zulu-windows/. (8u181, 3 months old)
- OJDKbuild: https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild#downloads-for-windows-x86_64 (8u191)
- Oracle: https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/8 (8u0, ~4 years old). **Avoid this at all costs for production**.
- Red Hat: https://developers.redhat.com/products/openjdk/download/ (8u181, 3 months old)

Comment: Would there be any difference in where you get your build?

Comment: Yes. Probably very minor, but some differences. The following is my personal understanding. In a general sense, the compilers and compilation settings would differ. I know the OJDKbuild and the Red Hat builds are generally very close to how OpenJDK is configured on Linux. So it would use the same set of underlying libraries for things like font rendering, displaying images and so on. I expect AdaptOpenJDK builds to be close to stock OpenJDK. I dont know anything about the Azul build.

Comment: from personal experience, would you have any recommendation on which build to use?

Comment: I work for Red Hat (I used to work on OpenJDK itself). I am obviously going to recommend ours :) Second would be ojdkbuild which is also maintained by a Red Hatter.

Comment: fair enough :) Thanks for your help.