# OpenJdk 8 for windows 64 bit

Tags: java

We are planning to migrate to OpenJDK 8, but we are only finding binaries for window 7 in BCD license.(  Oracle Binary Code License ) on  https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/8

We are looking for all windows compatible versions of open JDK and is BCD license that can use in production ( as Free to use)?

Comment: [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/).

Comment: Thanks @ElliottFrisch, but we are looking for oracle openjdk 8 .

Comment: You're going to be looking for a **long** time. Oracle doesn't provide an openjdk 8; [*End of Public Updates of Java SE 8
Java SE 8 has gone through the End of Public Updates process for legacy releases.*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/java-se-support-roadmap.html#:~:text=Java%20SE%208%20has%20gone,Personal%2C%20Development%20and%20other%20Users.) Unless you mean the [reference implementation](http://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/8). But you should probably be using AdoptOpenJDK because Oracle isn't updating the reference anymore (looks like since February 2015).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenJDK availability for Windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991508/openjdk-availability-for-windows-os)