# JDK as Zip File only not JRE

Tags: java-7

Where can I get the latest jdk as a zip file. I don't want the jre, I want the full jdk. I can't run exe's or even request windows installer so it's impossible for me to download the .exe and run it. Also I can't access some uploading sites like Drop box or 4shared. Is there any ftp or place that I can get just zipped up jdk? Thanks you very much. Jportable is not good enough, Thanks.

Comment: I have deleted my answer as it pertained to the JRE, and not the JDK.  Sorry for the confusion.  You may not have any options at this point.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback thought. Appreciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the latest JRE / JDK as a zip file rather than EXE or MSI installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619662/how-can-i-get-the-latest-jre-jdk-as-a-zip-file-rather-than-exe-or-msi-installe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really simple but, you have to make it yourself.

First, download the JDK from the Oracle Website.

Second, extract all the contents using 7zip or other extracting utility.

Third, navigate through the extracted content and use Java's "unpack200" to convert all the ".pack" files (there's a couple of them) into jar files. You can delete the ".pack" files afterwards if desired.

Note: In order to use unpack200 you need to have a JDK  installed on the system. Navigate to the jdk1.x.x_xx/bin folder an run the utility from the command line.

Example: unpack200 rt.pack rt.jar

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/java/  all the version are available. enjoy. all are ZIP

Comment: Not all versions, are avaible starting from 8 to 15.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, Oracle would provide us with the option of downloading the JDK binaries as a ZIP package instead of forcing us to use the Windows installer. But since they don't, why don't you try downloading the ZIP distribution of another Oracle product that already includes a JDK (e.g. Oracle SQLDeveloper). And please be sure to come back here and let us know if this approach worked out for you. I'm sure there are tons of folks out there looking for workaround too.

Answer (score 0):

You can install jdk (with installer, uncheck 'public jre' option), zip installation folder.
Then uninstall jdk. Now you have a jdk zip, you can unzip wherever.

I'm using jdk this way on Windows Vista, both jdk 1.6, and 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue - to get a zip version of JDK7 on my PC. Tried to extract the exe installer and was happy to find that I got a set of folders including jdk,jre, lib,bin etc (similar to the set up that you get by running the installer for Jdk8). But my happiness was short lived - Eclipse did not recognize this path as a valid JDK / JRE installation , while I set up the additional Run time environments.

The fix is to run the exe installer and install it in a different path , outside Program files, so that it doesnt mess up your Java home settings or JRE versions for other client programs.