# Install JRE when the same version is already present

Tags: installation, java

I'm trying to install a `jre-6u43-windows-i586` on my computer in static silent mode. This is a part of another installer. I run

```
jre-6u43-windows-i586.exe /s STATIC=1 INSTALLDIR=D:\\java1
```

And it installs great. Then, I'm trying to install it one more time, like

```
jre-6u43-windows-i586.exe /s STATIC=1 INSTALLDIR=D:\\java2
```

and it does not installs till I delete previous installation via `Programs and Features`.

How can I create a completely standalone JRE installation, so it does not lists in `Programs and Features`, does not registers itself in registry and so on. So, that I can create as many embedded installations as I want.

P.S. I know that I can just pack once installed JRE and then unpack it anywhere, but maybe there is more proper way of doing this?

Comment: Why closing this, moderators?

Comment: It is not closed. Someone voted to close but that doesn't necessarily mean that it will be closed.

Comment: @maba I know. My previous related question about installers was closed as not constructive. It was a bit unconstructive, but... The problem exists for me. I'll even accept "No way to do this" answer if it is true, but I want to be sure.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619662/where-can-i-get-the-latest-jre-jdk-as-a-zip-file-i-mean-no-exe-installer) is quite similar to yours even though it isn't pure new. See if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can make use of the Portable Java that you can find [here](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable).

I think it does what you want and it won't clutter the registry.

Comment: Can it be installed in silent mode as a part of another installer? Seems like it is NSIS installer, but `/S` and `/D` options does not work.