# No "src.zip" when extracting JDK installer

Tags: java, installation

I have followed this procedure : [How can I get the latest JRE / JDK as a zip file rather than EXE or MSI installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619662/where-can-i-get-the-latest-jre-jdk-as-a-zip-file-i-mean-no-exe-installer#answer-6571736). In order to get JDK w/o admin rights.
However, I still miss the source archive "src.zip".

When I open the installer with 7-Zip, it only shows "tools.zip" file. Here is the command-line output:

```
C:\Users\mlogan\Downloads>7z.exe l jdk-7u45-windows-i586.exe

7-Zip 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

Listing archive: jdk-7u45-windows-i586.exe

--
Path = jdk-7u45-windows-i586.exe
Type = PE
CPU = x86
Characteristics = Executable 32-bit
Created = 2013-10-08 17:03:06
Physical Size = 129487776
Headers Size = 1024
Checksum = 129505985
Image Size = 129503232
Section Alignment = 4096
File Alignment = 512
Code Size = 62976
Initialized Data Size = 129425408
Uninitialized Data Size = 0
Linker Version = 10.0
OS Version = 5.1
Image Version = 0.0
Subsystem Version = 5.1
Subsystem = Windows GUI
DLL Characteristics = Relocated NX-Compatible TerminalServerAware
Stack Reserve = 1048576
Stack Commit = 4096
Heap Reserve = 1048576
Heap Commit = 4096
Image Base = 4194304
----
Path = .rsrc\JAVA_CAB10\111
Size = 83877914
Packed Size = 83877914
--
Path = .rsrc\JAVA_CAB10\111
Type = Cab
Method = LZX
Blocks = 1
Volumes = 1

Date       Time     Attr          Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2013-10-08 08:42:32 ....A    181321555               tools.zip
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
                             181321555    129487776  1 files, 0 folders
```

Have you any idea on how to retrieve the source archive ?

Comment: You can unpack it from the linux version. It is exactly the same.

Comment: A little bit update for this section: On the **step 4 the pathes was changed**. I have unzipped jdk-8u131-windows-x64.exe and the src zip was in **.rsrc\1033\JAVA_CAB9\/** folder's **110** named cabinet file (you can unzip it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PeterLawrey suggested, the best way is to use Linux distribution.

Answer (score 2):

According to the latestest answer by Piero Ottuzzi in his post http://www.brucalipto.org/java/how-to-create-a-portable-jdk-1-dot-8-on-windows, Oracle seems to no longer include src.zip from update 45.
You could always use tools.zip to have a portable JDK.

Steps to follow on Windows to have a portable JDK:

1. Download the installer, eg. jdk-8u51-windows-x64.exe, into a folder, eg. "downloads", that contains 7z.exe.
2. Extract tools.zip from the installer with 7-Zip: open a command prompt and type

   ```
   D:\downloads>7z x jdk-8u51-windows-x64.exe
   ```
3. Extract the content of tools.zip to a folder, say "jdk", with 7-Zip: type in the command prompt

   ```
   D:\downloads>7z x tools.zip -ojdk
   ```
4. Move to the folder jdk and transform .pack files to .jar files: type in the command prompt

   ```
   D:\downloads>cd jdk
   D:\downloads\jdk>for /r %x in (*.pack) do .\bin\unpack200 -r "%x" "%~dx%~px%~nx.jar"
   ```

The folder jdk is the wanted portable jdk. To test it, type in the command prompt:

```
D:\downloads\jdk>.\bin\java -version
```

You would get

```
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of missing "src.zip". The right answer has been given by @PeterLawrey : uses Linux distribution. They are mostly same.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract **src.zip** by following the steps mentioned below.

**Note:** Steps are mentioned for **jdk-7u80-windows-x64.exe**. Steps for JDK7 and JDK8 (for both 32bit and 64bit) are similar.

**Step 1**

Execute the offline installer **jdk-7u80-windows-x64.exe**. Let the setup screen appear. Don't press the **Next** button.

[image]

**Step 2**

Now now in file explorer go to the directory

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java
```

where `UserName` is replaced by actual user name.

**Note:** For JDK 8 use the directory

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\LocalLow\Oracle\Java
```

[image]

Now the **MSI** and **CAB** files for JDK 7u80 64 bit installation will be in the directory **jdk1.7.0_80_x64**.

**Note:** For 32 bit JDK 7u80 installation the corresponding directory will be **jdk1.7.0_80**.

**Step 3**

Copy this folder to some other suitable location. Now cancel the JDK installation.

**Step 4**

Now in the copied folder you will find following files:

1. *jdk1.7.0_80.msi* - MSI for JDK installation.
2. *sj170800.cab* - Contains files required for stand alone JRE installation.
3. *ss170800.cab* - Contains file **src.zip**.
4. *st170800.cab* - Contains file **tools.zip**.
5. *sz170800.cab* - Contains file **COPYRIGHT**.

Comment: Without admin rights, the MSI isn't opened. So you don't access to any installer screen.

Comment: Yes, You need admin rights to execute MSI. But the original question is about how to get src.zip from Windows JDK installer.

Comment: No it's about to retrieve "src.zip" w/o admin rights ;)