# How to install an old version of JDK in windows 7?

Tags: java, java-6

I already have some version installed on the machine, 1.7 and 1.6.

Now I have the need to install version 1.5, but when I try to install an error occurs, speaking to uninstall the versions that I have the Java (JDK).

I have no chance because I have other applications using these versions, is there any possibility to do this without uninstalling these versions I already  have ?

Thank in advance !

[image]

Comment: What error are you getting? You can install multiple versions of Java on the same machine, as long as you install them in different directories.

Comment: I just installed 1.5 on Windows 10, without uninstalling my 1.7 & 1.8 versions. Package downloaded from [The oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html)?

Comment: I edited my question, putting an image of the error, however, I don´t have this version installed in my computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bypassing the installer is bit of work, but doable. How to extract Java from the EXE installer is described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6571736/73652

Answer (score 1):

The JDK is a package of tools for developing Java-based software.

1. Check your system architecture in the control panel, i.e. 32 or 64-bit.
2. Click on C → program folder → java folder.

If there is no JDK folder present, then follow the below steps:

3. Search in Google JDK download.
4. Scroll to bottom, and check for the system architecture of your system.
5. Click the download link and wait till the download is finished.
6. In downloads click on show in folder.
7. Click on the JDK icon and click on next until the setup process is completed.

Please find this video along with steps for [JDK Install](https://www.selenium-webdriver.com/jdk-installation).