# How can I get JAVA 9 JRE / JDK as a zip file rather than EXE or MSI installer?

Tags: java, java-9

How can I get JAVA 9 JRE / JDK as a zip file rather than EXE or MSI installer?

https://jdk9.java.net/download/

Comment: Just wondering if anyone has got an answer to this?  If Oracle's plan for the future is to stop publishing relocatable packages of the JRE, then for sure many of us will get into big trouble with our apps that use an embedded JRE.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at https://jdk9.java.net/ carefully there's "JDK 9 Early Access with Project Jigsaw" that is actually zip download.

Comment: This link is no more available. Please use http://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/9 link to download jdk9 zip file

Answer (score 6):

You can download JDK 9 zip file from [Java Platform, Standard Edition 9 Reference Implementations](http://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/9)

Answer (score 3):

As mentionend you can download the jigsaw distribution or you can follow the instructions from [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html) to build your own distribution.

Answer (score 2):

From here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6571736/8714033

- Create working JDK directory (`C:\JDK` in this case)
- [Download][1] latest version of JDK from Oracle (for example `jdk-7u7-windows-x64.exe`)
- [Download][2] and install 7-Zip (or download [7-Zip portable][3] version if you are not administrator)
- With 7-Zip extract all the files from `jdk-XuXX-windows-x64.exe` into the directory `C:\JDK`
- Execute the following commands in `cmd.exe`:

  - `cd C:\JDK\.rsrc\1033\JAVA_CAB10`
  - `extrac32 111`
- Unpack `C:\JDK\.rsrc\1033\JAVA_CAB10\tools.zip` with 7-zip
- Execute the following commands in `cmd.exe`:

  - `cd C:\JDK\.rsrc\1033\JAVA_CAB10\tools\`
  - `for /r %x in (*.pack) do .\bin\unpack200 -r "%x" "%~dx%~px%~nx.jar"` (this will convert all `.pack` files into `.jar` files)
- Copy all contents of `C:\JDK\.rsrc\1033\JAVA_CAB10\tools` where you want your JDK to be
- Setup `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` manually to point to your JDK dir and its BIN subdirectory.

Though my experience was a bit different, tools.zip can be in a different place depending on JDK version.

Answer (score 1):

You can download JDK 9 Early-Access Builds from [**jdk.java.net**](http://jdk.java.net/9/), All other locations ([jdk9-builds](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html), [jdk9.java.net](https://jdk9.java.net/)) are not accessible/migrated.