# How can I install jdk 1.6 without admin rights?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-6

I'm student in a company and I don't have rights to install but I need to install a jdk 1.6 in Eclipse Helios.

I've tried some "tricks" with unzip the .exe but I don't have the "tools.zip" in the unziped folder.

So any other methods ?

Comment: Go and speak to IT and explain why you need the application. If it's for work purposes then they'll be able to install it for you.

Comment: Indeed. It's not wise to start installing software if the company has a policy for that. You could get fired in the worst case.

Comment: I have permission from the CEO, but he's not an IT, and the IT is in holidays... so why I must to manage myself. However, thanks for the advice ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is discussed in this thread.
The first answer should solve your problem. There is a portable version of Java available which you can use.

[Solution on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619662/how-can-i-get-the-latest-jre-jdk-as-a-zip-file-rather-than-exe-or-msi-installe)