# how can I get jdk for java version 1.7.0_101?

Tags: java, java-7

I have to install OpenDJ 2.6.0, I ned jdk for how can I get jdk for java version 1.7.0_101 ?

Wher can I get it ? Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the latest JRE / JDK as a zip file rather than EXE or MSI installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619662/how-can-i-get-the-latest-jre-jdk-as-a-zip-file-rather-than-exe-or-msi-installe)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_7_updates):

- Java SE 7 Update 101
- Released: 2016-04-18
- Highlights: **Not available publicly**, only available through the Java SE Support program and in Solaris 10's Recommended Patchset Cluster; 22 security fixes.

Contact Oracle about getting coverage under the Java SE Support program

Answer (score 0):

That specific update of  JDK7 is no longer available. You closest thing  you'll get is a different JDK7 download from the [Oracle Archive](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html) page.