# Oracle JDK 9 - convert exe into zip - src.zip is missing

Tags: windows-installer, java-9

We need to add some settings to the jdk the developers use. For java 8 its encryption and truststore certificates, for java 9 its only additional truststore certificates.

We have a batch file to convert the installer exe into a zip, which works fine (using 7zip to extract the .exe file, then the tools.zip inside, then convert *.pack files into *.jar files). Similar [as it was done for jdk 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619662/how-can-i-get-the-latest-jre-jdk-as-a-zip-file-rather-than-exe-or-msi-installe/38898085). Then import the additional certificates into cacerts using the keytool from the extracted files.

Weirdly the `src.zip` file is missing. I could only find it in the temporary folder from the executed installer in `/c/Users/me/AppData/LocalLow/Oracle/Java/jdk9.0.1_x64`. But not in tools.zip extracted from the installer.

Currently I also download the linux jdk-9.tar.gz file and use the src.zip from there - but that file differs from the original src.zip the installer itself is able to copy. So where does the installer take that file from??

Any idea would be welcome!