# JDK 1.8 not being installed, only JRE on Windows

Tags: java, java-8

I'm trying to make a Spring application with Kotlin and stumbled in a problem with the problem `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` on class `KotlinJpaSubplugin`. I went to Oracle's site to download JDK 1.8 (https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). The problem is, the installer only installs the JRE and not JDK. I'm not very good with java versions, so what I'm missing?

Here is an image of the java folder in my PC. Only JRE 1.8 is installed, the only JDK is the old 1.7.

[image]

Comment: Which JDK 8 version did you download and when? The timestamp on these directories are quite old. From the attached screenshot are these 32 bit or 64 bit versions? Would it be possible that you downloaded a different bit version from the one's in the image? In that case your installation would be in another directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you've provided is correct.

You've most likely downloaded one of these items:

- Windows x86  201.64 MB   jdk-8u202-windows-i586.exe
- Windows x64  211.58 MB   jdk-8u202-windows-x64.exe

Something you can do:

- Make sure to check both '**Program Files\Java**' and '**Program Files (x86)\Java**' folders. By default JDK should be installed there.
- Use OS level search, to look for '**jdk1.8**' or '**1.8.0**' folders
- In case you're still missing it, you can try to manually extract the JDK folder from installer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/25384578/3523579

Comment: I was only checking on `Program Files (x86)\Java` folder and it was installing on `Program Files\Java`

Answer (score -1):

For whatever reason, `Windows x86   202.73 MB   jdk-8u221-windows-i586.exe` only installs a jre. get `Windows x64   215.35 MB   jdk-8u221-windows-x64.exe` which will install a JDK folder.