# Could not download JDK from Oracle

Tags: java, download, jvm, java-11

I tried to download JDK From Oracle. The following is the message from from Oracle website :

> Thank you for accessing https://edelivery.oracle.com/obrar.cgi
>
> In compliance with U.S. and applicable Export laws we are unable to
> process your request.  Please contact RPLS-Ops_ww@oracle.com if you
> believe you are receiving this notice in error.

```
Debug Info: Edge IP=184.50.110.178, Client IP=136.228.129.154, Client Country=KH, Client Region=Not Available
```

[Message in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvv1M.png)

Comment: I guess you can't access to law restrictions. You could use an alternate mirror or may be a proxy.

Comment: So did you contact RPLS-Ops_ww@oracle.com?

Comment: @Andreas Yes I did. But got no response until now.

Comment: I suggest you download an OpenJDK version which is available everywhere.

Comment: This appears to be the case with OpenJDK as well. See the "International Use Restrictions" section on their download page: https://jdk.java.net/19

Answer (score 4):

There are some countries that Oracle embargoes - ie. prohibits from downloading any of their products.

From :
http://www.oracle.com/us/products/export/export-regulations-345813.html

> Any company or national of Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Sudan, Syria, and
>   the Crimea region. Export licensing of commodities or services
>   intended for these countries is presumed denied;

What you could try is downloading a portable version - eg, see :
[How can I get the latest JRE / JDK as a zip file rather than EXE or MSI installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619662/how-can-i-get-the-latest-jre-jdk-as-a-zip-file-rather-than-exe-or-msi-installe)